# What does char 160 mean in my source code?

Tags: c#, .net

I am formatting numbers to string using the following format string "# #.##", at some point I need to turn back these number strings like (1 234 567) into something  like 1234567. I am trying to strip out the empty chars but found that

```
value = value.Replace(" ", "");
```

for some reason and the string remain 1 234 567. After looking at the string I found that

value[1] is 160.

I was wondering what the value 160 means?

Comment: There's a nice applet built into Windows to discover these kind of Unicode codepoints.  Use Charmap.exe

Comment: I tried to run it but I could not on Windows 2008

Comment: @HansPassant Did you said applet in 2010?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The answer is to look in [Unicode Code Charts](http://unicode.org/charts) - where you'll find the [Latin-1 supplement chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf); this shows that U+00A0 (160 as per your title, not 167 as per the body) is a non-breaking space.

Comment: I looked at the "Latin-1 supplement chart" that you referred to. I see the "00A0" line, but it doesn't say anywhere that it's the 160 character. I had the same problem as gyurisc and your answer solved it, but how did u find out that U+00A0 refers to 160?

Comment: @MaxS.: Hex 00A0 = decimal 160.

Answer (score 30):

char code `160` would be `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 28):

Maybe you could to use a regex to replace those empty chars:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\p{Z}", "");
```

This will remove ["any kind of whitespace or invisible separator"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Answer (score 14):

`value.Replace(Convert.ToChar(160).ToString(),"")`

Comment: value.Replace(((char)160).ToString(),"") for less typing

Answer (score 3):

This is a fast (and fairly readable) way of removing any characters classified as white space using [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (value.Length);
foreach (char c in value)
{
    if (!char.IsWhiteSpace (c))
        sb.Append (c);
}
string value= sb.ToString();
```

As [dbemerlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253984/dbemerlin) points out, if you know you will only need numbers from your data, you would be better use [`Char.IsNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y.aspx) or the even more restrictive [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (value.Length);
foreach (char c in value)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(c))
        sb.Append (c);
}
string value= sb.ToString();
```

If you need numbers and decimal seperators, something like this should suffice:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (value.Length);
foreach (char c in value)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(c)|c == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator )
        sb.Append (c);
}
string value= sb.ToString();
```

Comment: How about the decimal separator? Will Char.IsDigit() and Char.IsNumber() skip that too?

Comment: @AskAboutGadgets.com, yes IsNumber and IsDigit return false for a decimal seperator. I have added a new example

Comment: I would prefer "||" in the condition instead "|" for readability.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [char overload version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
value = value.Replace(Convert.ToChar(160), ' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with extended methods:

```
public static class ExtendedMethods
{
    public static string NbspToSpaces(this string text)
    {
        return text.Replace(Convert.ToChar(160), ' ');
    }
}
```

And it can be used with this code:

```
value = value.NbspToSpaces();
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't be the preferred method to replace all empty characters (and this is what the questioner wanted to do) with the Regex Method which Rubens already posted?

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\p{Z}", "");
```

or what Expresso suggests:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\p{Zs}", "");
```

The difference here is that \p{Z} replaces any kind of whitespace or invisible separator whereas the \p{Zs} replaces a whitespace character that is invisible, but does take up space.
You can read it here (Section Unicode Categories):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Using RegEx has the advantage that only one command is needed to replace also the normal whitespaces and not only the non-breaking space like explained in some answers above.

If performance is the way to go then of course other methods should be considered but this is out of scope here.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: To replace spaces and the weird ASCII char 160 in the active cell:

```
ActiveCell.Text = Replace(Trim(ActiveCell.Text), ChrW(160), "")
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?