# SQL Server : RTRIM not working to remove empty spaces

Tags: sql-server, trim

One of the column values in my tables have empty space at the end of each string.

In my select query, I am trying to trim the empty space at the end of string but the value is not getting trimmed.

```
SELECT
    EmpId, RTRIM(Designation) AS Designation, City 
FROM
    tblEmployee
```

This is not trimming the empty space, not just this even the `LTRIM(RTRIM(Designation) AS Designation` is not working.

I also tried

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(56), LTRIM(RTRIM(Designation))) AS [Designation]
```

Nothing is trimming the empty space at the end of the string...

Any help appreciated

**EDIT**

Thanks to suggestions in the comments, I checked what the last value was in the column using `ASCII()`. It is `160` is a [non-breaking space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2132372/6167855).

How can I remove this non-breaking space?

Comment: What makes you think that the spaces aren't being trimmed? You need to show a **reproducible** example of this happening.

Comment: And what makes you think the characters not being trimmed are spaces?

Comment: What @MartinSmith is saying (which is a great point) is are you sure they aren't CR, LF, TAB, etc?

Comment: To help, run this on the rows where there is a *space* and let us know the results. `select ascii(right(YourColumn,1)) from YourTable`

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the version of SQL Server you're using, post the table definition so that we can see how `Designation` is defined, and report what happens when you modify your query to return `'*' + LTrim(RTrim(Designation)) + '*'`

Comment: @scsimon when i execute the query the value is 160 and the column type of Designation field is nvarchar(150)

Comment: @Brian the output value is like  -- *product executive * -- when i execute your query

Comment: Then you need to use `replace(yourColumn,char(160),’’)` or to ensure you only remove the last instance, `left(yourColumn,len(yourColumn) - 1)`. Your space isn’t a normal space.

Comment: my concern with `left(yourColumn,len(yourColumn) - 1)` is that if there is no empty space at the end of the string then it might remove the alphabetic character... will using `replace(yourColumn,char(160),’’)` have any impact ?

Comment: Good concern. You can check if that space is there with a case or iff. Otherwise replace will work but it will replace that character everywhere in the string. If this odd space is only at the end then you are good to use replace.

Comment: @scsimon thanks a lot, i see using replace the empty spaces are not trimmed in the middle of sentence other than the special empty char at the end....

Comment: That is correct, which means your spaces in the sentence are real spaces not this odd space. Glad it worked

Comment: Glad that helped show the problem.  Sticking an asterisk at the ends of strings is a trick I learned many years ago.  BTW, @scsimon, I think that user 3198688 has improved his question to the point that the powers that be can unflag it.  It looks to me like it's a good question now.

Comment: I agree and nominated it for reopening. I'll edit the question. @MartinSmith and others will need to reopen.

Comment: @scsimon thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

> How can I remove this non-breaking space?

Just replace it with `''` and use `CHAR()` function as

```
SELECT REPLACE(YourColumn, CHAR(160), '')
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the similar problem, Use below script to remove the space in case trim function not work -

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([ColumnName], CHAR(10), 
CHAR(32)),CHAR(13), CHAR(32)),CHAR(160), CHAR(32)),CHAR(9),CHAR(32))))
FROM [TableName]
```

For more info visit this page - http://www.ashishblog.com/trim-not-removing-spaces-in-sql/

Answer (score 1):

Since the value can contain non-breaking spaces you need to replace those with regular spaces before doing the trim:

```
SELECT
    EmpId, RTRIM(REPLACE(Designation,char(160),' ')) AS Designation, City 
FROM
    tblEmployee
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these will work if your datatype is Varchar. Make sure to change your datatype to Nvarchar. Then use trim.