# print lines with blank spaces or white spaces

Tags: awk, sed, aix

I am having dificulty trying to print lines with white space only and excluding the rest like below.

Inside test.txt

```
francoiv|538|
gerardl|520|
icell|548|
icell  |787|
ieppcnf|791|
ieppix |788|
ieppvas|792|
ifastrk|790|
iinter|558|
iinter |793|
ixaeppix|795|
ixaepprp|796|
ixaint|772|
ixaint |794|
ixarocel|771|
ixaroint|773|
karsc001|1051|
mafokokg|535|
makgotma|528|
```

The expected output I require is below.

```
icell  |787|
ieppix |788|
iinter |793|
ixaint |794|
```

I have tried so many sed and awk options online and I can't seem to come right. The number of white spaces can be more than 2 so I was trying to use a command that can find before the pipe [|] a whitespace or blank character, but I can't find a way to do this.

When I use cat -v test.txt to display special character, I get below.

```
francoiv|538|
gerardl|520|
icell|548|
icellM- M- |787|
ieppcnf|791|
ieppixM- |788|
ieppvas|792|
ifastrk|790|
iinter|558|
iinterM- |793|
ixaeppix|795|
ixaepprp|796|
ixaint|772|
ixaintM- |794|
ixarocel|771|
ixaroint|773|
karsc001|1051|
mafokokg|535|
makgotma|528|
```

Not sure what M- means

Comment: Also not working

Comment: We would need to know what these "spaces" are. `od -tx1 test.txt` could help. Meanwhile you can maybe try `grep '[[:space:]]|' test.txt`.

Comment: [What is the "M- notation" and where is it documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694331/what-is-the-m-notation-and-where-is-it-documented)

Comment: Combine this with [What does char 160 mean in my source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132348/what-does-char-160-mean-in-my-source-code)

Comment: @dawg: The character 160 (hex `a0`) is not caught by `[[:space:]]`

Comment: Using `awk 'gsub(/\xa0/," ")' file`  would replace the `M- ` characters by a space.

Answer (score 2):

Some possibilities (tested with GNU tools):

```
$ grep '[^[:alnum:]|]' test.txt
icell  |787|
ieppix |788|
iinter |793|
ixaint |794|
```

```
$ grep '[^[:graph:]]' test.txt
icell  |787|
ieppix |788|
iinter |793|
ixaint |794|
```

```
$ awk '/[^\x00-\x7F]/' test.txt
icell  |787|
ieppix |788|
iinter |793|
ixaint |794|
```

Answer (score 1):

If the space is in the end of the first field, use:

```
$ awk -F\| '$1~/ +$/' file
icell  |787|
ieppix |788|
iinter |793|
ixaint |794|
```

Explained:

`awk -F\|` using awk, pipe is the field separator

`$1` first field

`~/ +$/` ends in one or more spaces

Comment: It didn't work... how? Is the data as you included in the question?

Comment: hmm. Thought. cat -v test.txt| grep "M- ". This works. This is not practical though

Comment: `M- ` is new to me. Try something like `head -4 file | hexdump -C` (if there is `M- ` in the 4th line)?

Comment: I do not have hexdump on our aix server. ksh: hexdump:  not found

Comment: Just to give insight, This is an unload from an informix database where I am trying to remove duplicate users so there is gibberish I need to delete and from what it looks like, the unload from the gibberish data is showing 'M- ' at the end of username. Not sure if this is informix unload doing this as a special character.

Comment: `awk -F\| '$1!~/^[a-z0-9]+$/' file` to print out lines where the first field is not just alpha numeric.

Comment: Based on @Luuk's link: `awk -F\| '$1~/0xA0+$/' file` ?

Comment: I gotta go. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Print only lines that contain (at least) one space:

```
$ grep ' ' test.txt
icell  |787|
ieppix |788|
iinter |793|
ixaint |794|
```

If you mean white space (ie, spaces, tabs) then:

```
$ grep -E '[[:space:]]' test.txt
icell  |787|
ieppix |788|
iinter |793|
ixaint |794|
```

Comment: No need for the `+` in that 2nd command.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `sed` solution, let `file.txt` content be

```
francoiv|538|
gerardl|520|
icell|548|
icell  |787|
ieppcnf|791|
ieppix |788|
ieppvas|792|
ifastrk|790|
iinter|558|
iinter |793|
ixaeppix|795|
ixaepprp|796|
ixaint|772|
ixaint |794|
ixarocel|771|
ixaroint|773|
karsc001|1051|
mafokokg|535|
makgotma|528|
```

then

```
sed '/[a-z0-9]|[0-9]/d' file.txt
```

gives output

```
icell  |787|
ieppix |788|
iinter |793|
ixaint |794|
```

Explanation: I instruct GNU `sed` to `d`elete lines when there is lowercase ascii letter or digit followed by pipe followed by digit. Others lines are printed (default action).

*(tested in GNU sed 4.8)*